# HTML5 Video Validation Error

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have the following markup, implemented using the [VideoJS](http://videojs.com/) player (I can include the js too, if it becomes necessary):

```
<video id="example_video_1" class="video-js" width="736" height="352" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop"> 
    <source src="a/v/jt_homevid.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>                         
    <source src="a/v/jt_homevid.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'>         
    <object id="flash_fallback_1" class="vjs-flash-fallback" width="736" height="352" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  data="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf"> 
        <param name="movie" value="http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.1.swf" /> 
        <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /> 
        <param name="flashvars" value='config={"playlist":["<? echo $currurl; ?>/a/v/slide-1-joshtaerk-cdcover.jpg", {"url": "<? echo $currurl; ?>/a/v/jt_homevid.mp4","autoPlay":false,"autoBuffering":true}]}' />         
        <img src="a/v/slide-1-joshtaerk-cdcover.jpg" width="736" height="352" alt="Poster Image" title="No video playback capabilities." /> 
    </object> 
</video>
```

And this is currently failing HTML validation, with the following error message:

> Line 152, Column 82: Element source not allowed as child of element video in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)…   
>    Contexts in which element source may be used:As a child of a media element, before any flow content or track elements.Content model for element video:If the element has a src attribute: zero or more track elements, then transparent, but with no media element descendants.If the element does not have a src attribute: zero or more source elements, then zero or more track elements, then transparent, but with no media element descendants.

I do understand that I maybe should not be trusting the W3C HTML5 validator at this point in it's development, but if I have miscoded, I would like to identify where, and how to prevent it in the future. Also, I'd like to be sure I am interpreting the error message correctly, which I think should happen along the way.

I cannot see how I have deviated from the allowed contexts for this element. It is a child of a media element (Specifically the `<video>` tag), it is before any 'flow content' I believe, because I cannot find the `<source>` element listed as flow content on the W3C (at [this link](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#flow-content)), and I do not have any `<track>` elements currently.

One thing I'm not certain about is the definition of 'then transparent' in the content model for the `<video>` element. From my understanding is that if elements inside the media elements are valid if they are also valid inside the parent of the media element (from this thread: [Can I have multiple src attributes in an HTML5 <audio> element? Or an src attribute and a <source> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554399/can-i-have-multiple-src-attributes-in-an-html5-audio-element-or-an-src-attribu)), and this is perhaps where I've misstepped, as I have the `<video>` element inside a `<div>` parent?

Can anyone confirm this as my mistake, or whether I should ignore the validation message? If this is a mistake, how else should I be laying out my content? By styling the video element directly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, and this does look like a validator bug.

[Validator.nu](http://validator.nu/), which is based on the same validator engine as the W3C validator, but is likely to be a later version, passes the mark-up without any errors.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have this error

[image]

with this html code:

```
<video class="tab" controls>
    Your browser does not support the &lt;video&gt; tag.
    <source src="img/holsbeek-HD720p.mov" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

But not if the sequence is right:

```
<video class="tab" controls>
    <source src="img/holsbeek-HD720p.mov" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support the &lt;video&gt; tag.
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug is now fixed in the HTML5 Validator.

Comment: Apparently not. I'm experiencing the same problem in 2018.

Comment: I am using this in 2020 and still shows the same problem. However everything works :)