# How can I get the string/message or code from a video tag error event?

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video

So this feels like a stupid question. Hopefully I'm just overlooking something obvious, but I am listening for an error on a video element. The error string actually shows in the console, and the error event fires properly, but when I look through the error object, I can't seem to find that string anywhere. My goal is to simply record this error for logging purposes. Another option is to get the error code -- anything really that could be logged to give our debuggers a clue as to what the problem actually was. Any idea how to get the error string or code from a video tag error object?

code:

```
$(this.video)
    .on( 'error', this.proxy(this.onVideoError));

onVideoError : function(e) {
  console.log(e, " the e");
  console.log(e.toString());//prints [object Object]
  console.log(e.code, " the code");// prints undefined
},
```

Comment: As far as I am aware, errors have a `name` and `message` property. [Error Objects and throwing your own errors](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/trycatch2.shtml)

Comment: I am not sure if your question is related to this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273864/html5-video-validation-error

Answer (score 0):

In my error handlers I am using the `err.name` and `err.message` members.
Since errors don't actually have a Code like in PHP or other languages, you might need to parse the message and name to create your own Codes.

```
var errorHandler = function(err) {

  // prints the name of the error
  console.log(err.name);

  // prints the description that is also shown in the error console
  console.log(err.message);

  // this works only in some browsers
  // line and stack are not supported by all vendors
  console.log(err.line, err.stack);
}
```